# Google sheets importxml on Facebook groups page

Tags: facebook, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape the number of photos statistic from a Facebook group (currently 432,780) at:

https://m.facebook.com/groups/553511078046085?view=info

I have copied the relevant xpath and used the following formula in Google Sheets:

=importxml("https://m.facebook.com/groups/553511078046085?view=info","//*[@id='u_0_y_OX']")

However, it doesn't work and keeps showing the error message "imported content is empty"

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API. Also Facebook uses a bunch of Javascript which I doubt Google execute.

Comment: Related [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/250491)